# How to append a part of xml in XML file while runtime?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

i have the following XML. I'm trying to update/append a part of XML at run-time.
but its quite hard.

```
<XML>
<FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
<FRUITS>
    <FRUIT>
        <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
        <ORANGE_FIELDS>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                <VALUE>1KG</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
        </ORANGE_FIELDS>
    </FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
```

this is the expectation !

```
<XML>
<FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
<FRUITS>
    <FRUIT>
        <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
        <ORANGE_FIELDS>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                <VALUE>1KG</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
            <FIELD>
                <KEY>MADE</KEY>
                <VALUE>Florida</VALUE>
            </FIELD>
        </ORANGE_FIELDS>
    </FRUIT>
</FRUITS>
```

Guide me how to handle the append in XML at run-time ?

Comment: You are tagging this question with sql/oracle/plsql technologies.  Do you mean to update the XML using those technologies?  If not, what is your coding language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `INSERTCHILDXML` in Oracle.

```
WITH t ( old_xml, child_xml, node, field_name) AS
      ( SELECT 
    '<XML>
    <FRUIT_SHOP>JARVIZ</FRUIT_SHOP>
    <FRUITS>
        <FRUIT>
            <FRUIT_NAME>ORANGE</FRUIT_NAME>
            <ORANGE_FIELDS>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>COLOUR</KEY>
                    <VALUE>LIGHT_RED</VALUE>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD>
                    <KEY>WEIGHT</KEY>
                    <VALUE>1KG</VALUE>
                </FIELD>
            </ORANGE_FIELDS>
        </FRUIT>
    </FRUITS>
    </XML>
    ' old_xml,

    '<FIELD>
     <KEY>MADE</KEY>
     <VALUE>Florida</VALUE>
     </FIELD>' child_xml,

      '/XML/FRUITS/FRUIT/ORANGE_FIELDS' node,
               'FIELD' field_name
       FROM dual)
SELECT
  INSERTCHILDXML(XMLTYPE(old_xml),
  node,
  field_name,
  XMLTYPE(child_xml))
FROM t;
```

Comment: I agree with that. any other chance to do it in Procedure ?

Comment: @AzhagiriS : Why would you want to accomplish it using procedure when oracle provides you the required functions? Moreover, if you want it in procedure you may use the INSERTCHILDXML function directly, with passing appropriate variables containing xmls, if you understand what i mean